# Imprimir itens de uma lista em sequencia selecionando apenas partes delas - Python

Tags: python, txt, texto

Eu tenho uma lista com vários elementos e quero imprimir todos em sequência, entretanto, eu quero apenas uma parte deste elemento que no caso abaixo são os códigos 61708... e 615c9...

```
lista = [["'id': '61708e546faa771a406e4aa3'"],["'id': '615c9413e4bf1834e150afda'"]]
for i in lista:
    print(lista[0][6:31])
```

Desta forma oque aparece pra mim é:

```
[]
[]
```

O meu intuito é que ela retornasse apenas os códigos em sequência, exemplo:

```
[61708e546faa771a406e4aa3]
[615c9413e4bf1834e150afda]
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?
A lista é bem maior, coloquei só 2 pra facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 1):

Preste atenção, você na verdade tem uma *lista de listas*, onde há um string dentro de cada uma das sublistas. Portanto, você precisa de mais um for loop para acessar o string em si.

Faça dessa forma:

```
lista = [["'id': '61708e546faa771a406e4aa3'"],["'id': '615c9413e4bf1834e150afda'"]]
for sublista in lista:
    for texto in sublista:
        codigo = texto[7:-1]
        print(codigo)
```

output:

```
61708e546faa771a406e4aa3
615c9413e4bf1834e150afda
```

Esta solução **presume** que o código de interesse sempre vai do sétimo caractere ao penúltimo, ignorando portanto os caracteres `'id': '` do começo e `'` do final do string. Se isso não se mantiver verdadeiro, a lógica de extração do código na linha `codigo = texto[7:-1]` deverá ser alterada, p. ex. usando o regex (módulo `re` da biblioteca padrão).

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu sou novato na linguagem e não achei nada na internet sobre e não aprendi no curso que estou fazendo.

Você me ajudou muito, obrigado pela atenção e pela resposta extremamente completa!